# Deploying EJB written in clojure to standalone application server

Tags: jakarta-ee, clojure, ejb, websphere

Does anyone have experineces combinig Clojure code with existing JavaEE infrastructure (It's the Webspehere Application Server 8 in my case)?

When creating a `jar` to be deployed to the Application Server, I put `(:aot [carina.stateless])` to `project.clj` (`carina.stateless` includes class and two interfaces needed for stateless EJB) and then running `lein jar` resulting in a huge `jar` comprised of all dependent clojure namespaces.

I tried to avoid `lein uberjar` as I intend to deploy some more applications to the same application server and make use of sharing jars but now, most of the code get precompiled.

Is there a way to avoid this AOT step producing a huge jar file if all I'm doing is implementing `javax.ejb.Remote` and extending `javax.ejb.Stateless`?

Comment: I found a way to create lightweight EJB with clojure and deploy without the need for AOT. I used small EJB written in java which uses `clojure.lang.RT` to compile clojure namespaces and to call clojure functions. Example project is available at github: https://github.com/alesk/clojure-javainterop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer:*

No, there isn't a way to do what you want. You may be able to pick out some shared libraries and move them up the class loader hierarchy in your app server, but it's 'probably' not worth the effort.

*But watch this space:*

Your problem is that you need (I expect) only some of clojure that your EJB uses.

At present clojure isn't modular, so you are forced to take all of clojure.jar and any dependencies.

It doesn't help you at the moment but the feature you need is 'tree shaking' whereby you can, through some as yet unspecified process, 'shake' your dependencies and all the bits you don't need fall out, leaving you with a small runtime and jar.

I believe this was mentioned at the most recent clojure conj in relation to deployments on small platforms like android.

Comment: Thank You! The jar is not that huge anyway, but that 'tree shaking' feature sounds really promising.